# Induction heating through a slightly magnetic material

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

Would be be possible to inductively heat a rod with with ~100 relative permeability enclosed in a tube with ~2 permeability?  The gap between the rod and the interior surface of the tube is uniform and at most 10% of the  radius of the rod

Some heating of the tube is acceptable, as long as most of the heat goes into the high permeability rod.

Assuming that this is possible, how is energy absorbed by the two materials related to their relative permeability?  Does the gap have between the rod and the tube have a significant effect?

Comment: Do you mean heated in an alternating magnetic field? Then you need to know the conductivity of the pipe and rod.

Comment: I do mean with an AC field.  The pipe and rod are both metal and have similar thermal and electrical conductivity.

Comment: Then the answer depends on the amplitudes of the magnetic field, the orientation of the field relative to the axis of the pipe, frequency, conductivity, pipe diameter and the wall thickness of the pipe.